# How simplify this code?

Tags: java, performance, jdbc

This code serves to update a customer's data in sql. How I can simplify this code? Is there another way to do this?

```
if (!clienteOld.getNome().equalsIgnoreCase(clienteNew.getNome())) {
        stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE CLIENTES SET NOME = '" + clienteNew.getNome() + "' WHERE ID = " + id1 + ";");
        criarLog("Ficha do cliente: " + clienteOld.getNome() + " foi atualizada -- NOME=" + clienteNew.getNome());
    }
    if (!clienteOld.getDataNascimento().equalsIgnoreCase(clienteNew.getDataNascimento())) {
        stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE CLIENTES SET DATA_NASCI = '" + clienteNew.getDataNascimento() + "' WHERE ID = " + id1 + ";");
        criarLog("Ficha do cliente: " + clienteOld.getNome() + " foi atualizada -- DATA NASCIMENTO=" + clienteNew.getDataNascimento());
    }
    if (!clienteOld.getMorada().equalsIgnoreCase(clienteNew.getMorada())) {
        stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE CLIENTES SET MORADA = '" + clienteNew.getMorada() + "' WHERE ID = " + id1 + ";");
        criarLog("Ficha do cliente: " + clienteOld.getNome() + " foi atualizada -- MORADA=" + clienteNew.getMorada());
    }
    if (!clienteOld.getPais().equalsIgnoreCase(clienteNew.getPais())) {
        stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE CLIENTES SET PAIS = '" + clienteNew.getPais() + "' WHERE ID = " + id1 + ";");
        criarLog("Ficha do cliente: " + clienteOld.getNome() + " foi atualizada -- PAIS=" + clienteNew.getPais());
    }
    if (!clienteOld.getNacionalidade().equalsIgnoreCase(clienteNew.getNacionalidade())) {
        stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE CLIENTES SET NACIONALIDADE = '" + clienteNew.getNacionalidade() + "' WHERE ID = " + id1 + ";");
        criarLog("Ficha do cliente: " + clienteOld.getNome() + " foi atualizada -- NACIONALIDADE=" + clienteNew.getNacionalidade());
    }
    if (!clienteOld.getBI().equalsIgnoreCase(clienteNew.getBI())) {
        stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE CLIENTES SET BI = '" + clienteNew.getBI() + "' WHERE ID = " + id1 + ";");
        criarLog("Ficha do cliente: " + clienteOld.getNome() + " foi atualizada -- BI=" + clienteNew.getBI());
    }
    if (!clienteOld.getTipoIndentificaçao().equalsIgnoreCase(clienteNew.getTipoIndentificaçao())) {
        stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE CLIENTES SET TIPO_IDENT = '" + clienteNew.getTipoIndentificaçao() + "' WHERE ID = " + id1 + ";");
        criarLog("Ficha do cliente: " + clienteOld.getNome() + " foi atualizada -- TIPO IDENTIFICAÇAO=" + clienteNew.getTipoIndentificaçao());
    }
```

Comment: Merge them into a single SQL query.

Comment: @Nikolas Easier said than done, but yes, the OP could build a single update string and then just execute that.

Comment: By the way, don't use language-specific characters (Portuguese), such as `ç` in code. And this code is also vulnerable against SQL injection - use Prepared Statement.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: A comment section is not for the long and complex articles - if I want to elaborate, I'd post the answer. The comment is just a hint.

Comment: Don't glue variables directly into SQL. Use statement parameters instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this logic:

```
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder("UPDATE CLIENTES SET ");
Map<String, String> cols = new HashMap<>();

if (!clienteOld.getNome().equalsIgnoreCase(clienteNew.getNome())) {
    cols.put("NOME", clienteNew.getNome());
}
if (!clienteOld.getDataNascimento().equalsIgnoreCase(clienteNew.getDataNascimento())) {
    cols.put("DATA_NASCI", clienteNew.getDataNascimento());
}
// and the other if statements
```

Then you can iterate the map and build your actual update statement:

```
int cnt = 0;
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : cols.entrySet()) {
    if (cnt > 0) sql.append(", ");
    sql.append(entry.getKey()).append(" = '").append(entry.getValue()).append("'");
    ++cnt;
}

sql.append(" WHERE ID = ").append(id1).append(";");
```

But note that this approach is *not* SQL injection safe.  If these values are coming from the outside, e.g. a UI, then you should absolutely be using a prepared statement.  There is nothing inherently wrong with using a separate statement for each if condition.  I only answered to show that you can cleanup your current approach, should it be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (!oldClient.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(newClient.getName())) {
        stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE CLIENTS SET NAME = '" + newClient.getName() +
                           "' WHERE ID = " + id1 + ";");
    }
    if (!oldClient.getBirthDate().equalsIgnoreCase(newClient.getBirthDate())) {
        stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE CLIENTS SET BIRTH = '" + newClient.getBirthDate() +
                           "' WHERE ID = " + id1 + ";");
    }
```

can be rewritten as

```
    if (!oldClient.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(newClient.getName()) ||
        !oldClient.getBirthDate().equalsIgnoreCase(newClient.getBirthDate())) {
        stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE CLIENTS SET NAME = '" + newClient.getName() +
                           "', BIRTH = '" + newClient.getBirthDate() +
                           "' WHERE ID = " + id1 + ";");
    }
```

This will perform better because it executes one SQL statement instead of two.  The fact that you are possibly setting two columns when only one needs to be set is probably of little consequence, compared with that.

Notes:

1. If you try to "optimize" the number of columns set, the code is more complicated; see Tim's answer.
2. This should probably be done with a `PreparedStatement` and statement parameters to avoid SQL injection.  If you follow the above pattern, the changes needed to use a `PreparedStatement` are straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use one query to update every fields :

```
"UPDATE CLIENTES SET DATA_NASCI "
    + "MORADA = '" + clienteNew.getMorada() + "'"
    + "PAIS = '" + clienteNew.getPais() + "'"
    + "NACIONALIDADE = '" + clienteNew.getNacionalidade() + "'"
    + "BI = '" + clienteNew.getBI() + "'"
    + "TIPO_IDENT = '" + clienteNew.getTipoIndentificaçao() + "'"
    + "WHERE ID = " + id1 + ";"
```

*Please use a `PreparedStatement` instead of this, this would be much safer !*

All you have to do is check if only one field have changed (to prevent the transaction doing nothing) using a condition check each field :

```
if (!clienteOld.getNome().equalsIgnoreCase(clienteNew.getNome()))
      || (clienteOld.getDataNascimento().equalsIgnoreCase(clienteNew.getDataNascimento())) 
    || (!clienteOld.getMorada().equalsIgnoreCase(clienteNew.getMorada()))
    || (!clienteOld.getPais().equalsIgnoreCase(clienteNew.getPais()))
    || (!clienteOld.getNacionalidade().equalsIgnoreCase(clienteNew.getNacionalidade())) 
    || (!clienteOld.getBI().equalsIgnoreCase(clienteNew.getBI())) 
    || (!clienteOld.getTipoIndentificaçao().equalsIgnoreCase(clienteNew.getTipoIndentificaçao()))
```

This can be a bit verbose ... so why not reduce this code a bit using Stream and some function references to compare and build a map of value to update :

First, the class `Bean` for our example :

```
class Bean {
    String firstname, lastname;

    public Bean(String firstname, String lastname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }
}
```

Then, let's create a mapping of `Column name` and `Function`, the function will allow us to use the getters of `Bean` :

```
Map<String, Function<Bean, String>> functions = new HashMap<>();
functions.put("FIRSTNAME", Bean::getFirstname);
functions.put("LASTNAME", Bean::getLastname);
```

Then, using `final` instance (to be used in a Predicate)

```
final Bean clienteNew = new Bean("Foo", "Bar");
final Bean clienteOld = new Bean("Foo", "Boo");


Map<String, String> values = functions.entrySet()
    .stream()
    //filter only the value that changed between clienteOld and clienteNew
    .filter(entry -> !entry.getValue().apply(clienteOld).equals(entry.getValue().apply(clienteNew)))
    //then collect the map `name -> new value`
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue().apply(clienteNew)));

System.out.println(values);
```

> {LASTNAME=Bar}

This will give you a `Map<String, String>` that can be used to create a `PreparedStatement` with only the column we want/need to edit.

If you have a new field, just need to add the mapping in the `functions` map and you are good to go. (this become a bit more complex with primitive type...)